# Pulling identifier variable from one data set to another in r

Tags: r, data.table

I hope someone can help me with the following problem: 
I'm working with two data tables in r: one containing weight measurements from users over four years, the other containing physical activity measurements from these same users over the same time period. I was looking for long breaks in the weight measurement data, these are my events of interest. I now want to extract physical activity data for the time frames of the event in the weight data. 
Some users may have several weighing-break events over the four years, so just userID won't be sufficient to extract the data. In the weight data set I have created a variable called events_stop which is an identifier of the specific weighing-break event. This variable does not yet exist in the physical activity data table. I'm struggling with adding this identifier to the physical activity data set.

My code so far looks as follows:
I first created a data table from the weight data which contains user_ID and events_stop, as well as the dates of the -20, -4 and +6 weeks time points which I later on want to pull into the physical activity data table 'steps.all3'

```
minus20andminus4 <- weight.all6[, lapply(.SD, min, na.rm=T), 
by=.(user_ID, events_stop), .SDcols = c("minus20", "minus4", "plus6")]
```

In order to be able to match the date data in minus20andminus4 with the physical activity data table I need to add the events_stop variable. To do this I wanted to match the rows where user_IDs are the same and dates fall within the period of the stopping event

```
steps.all3[, events_stop := ifelse(steps.all3$user_ID == minus20andminus4$user_ID 
& steps.all3$date_local >= minus20andminus4$minus20 
& steps.all3$date_local <= minus20andminus4$plus6, 
minus20andminus4$events_stop, NA)]
```

At this point I get the error message:

```
Error in Ops.factor(steps.all3$user_ID, minus20andminus4$user_ID) :
level sets of factors are different
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The weight data looks like this:

```
user_ID    date_local    weight_kg    events_stop    minus20      minus4      plus 6
134        2016-01-07    99.2         160            2016-01-07   2016-04-28   2016-07-07
134        2016-02-08    99.6         160            2016-01-07   2016-04-28   2016-07-07
134        2016-02-10    99.5         160            2016-01-07   2016-04-28   2016-07-07
134        2016-03-13    99.1         160            2016-01-07   2016-04-28   2016-07-07
222        2014-04-20    78.2         181            2014-04-20   2014-08-03   2014-11-20
222        2014-05-02    78.3         181            2014-04-20   2014-08-03   2014-11-20
222        2014-05-07    78.9         181            2014-04-20   2014-08-03   2014-11-20
222        2016-08-15    82.1         195            2016-08-13   2016-12-03   2017-02-11
222        2016-08-22    82.6         195            2016-08-13   2016-12-03   2017-02-11
```

So there is one row per weight measurement.

Same structure for step data:

```
user_ID    date_local    steps    
134        2016-01-09    10231
134        2016-02-10    8972
222        2014-04-28    10332
222        2014-05-01    7782
222        2016-09-04    8432
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: can you please post some data for weight.all6 and steps.all3?

Comment: Sure! I've added some example data in the question post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible one of the `date_local`s from `steps.all3` could fall within more than on period? If that's the case, it may be worth doing an inequality join. Does the following capture what you're looking for?

```
minus20andminus4[steps.all3,
                 .(i.user_ID, i.date_local, i.steps, x.events_stop, x.minus20, x.minus4, x.plus6),
                 on = .(user_ID = user_ID, minus20 <= date_local, plus6 >= date_local),
                 allow.cartesian = TRUE]

   i.user_ID i.date_local i.steps x.events_stop  x.minus20   x.minus4    x.plus6
1:       134   2016-01-09   10231           160 2016-01-07 2016-04-28 2016-07-07
2:       134   2016-02-10    8972           160 2016-01-07 2016-04-28 2016-07-07
3:       222   2014-04-28   10332           181 2014-04-20 2014-08-03 2014-11-20
4:       222   2014-05-01    7782           181 2014-04-20 2014-08-03 2014-11-20
5:       222   2016-09-04    8432           195 2016-08-13 2016-12-03 2017-02-11
```